# Testing connected react component that needs params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, redux, karma-mocha

I'm trying to test a connected react component that needs a props.params.id to call action creators. When I try to test that the component is connected to the store I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={PostsIndex}/>
        <Route path="posts/:id" component={ShowPost}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));


describe('ConnectedShowPost', ()=> {
    let initialState = {
      posts: { postsList: postsListData, post: postData, error: '' },
      comments: {showComments: false},
      auth: {authenticated: true}
    };

    store = mockStore(initialState);

    connectedShowPost = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedShowPost/></Provider>);
    showPost = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(connectedShowPost, ShowPost)[0];


    expect(showPost.props.posts.post).toEqual(postData);
  })
```

I've tried including params in the store but that doesn't work since params is not hooked up to the store when used inside the component.

I've also tried passing it in as an ownProps argument and that didn't work either.

Passing it in to  the ConnectedShowPost component as a props causes all other state items in the store to be undefined..

Also tried to directly set showPost.props.params = {id: '123} which didnt work either..

Any ideas on how to get this test to work?

Comment: When you say passing an ownProps do you mean doing this? <ConnectedShowPost {...props} />

Comment: no i meant in the connect for example: mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) { id: ownProps.params.id}

Comment: I think if you specify a props object (similar to initial state), apply it to the ConnectedShowPost like this: <ConnectedShowPost {...props} /> it will work. However I think you should also consider how you are testing. In the Redux documentation http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html, it is recommended to test the "unconnected" component and then specify the props that is receives. This allows you to unit test the functionality of your component separately from depending on the state of your application.

Comment: That seems to work but I don't think it would prove that the state is being passed from the mockStore but rather from the props object we pass from spread operator. You're right on account of testing the unconnected component. Right now this has me stumped though

Comment: Well your `props.params.id`won't be related to `initialState`.  `initialState` is being passed into a Redux store. But react-router does not use this store - it passes parameters directly to the component you are asking it to render based on the path. So in testing you will have to pass these parameters directly to the component. I guess it's also possible to somehow specify the window.url, wrap your test in a `<Router>` and try to use that to get it to pass the params down...but I think you will find much more beneficial testing to eliminate this complication and test the component itself.

Comment: Yea I think you're right this is proving to be less beneficial than just testing the component thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your connected component receives a param like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps)
{
    const { match: { params } } = ownProps;
    console.log(params.id);

    return {
         ......
    };
}
```

Then, In your test it's possible to inject that param as traditional props. Check out the next example:

```
    wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter>
            <ConnectedContainer
                store={store}
                match={
                    {
                        params: {
                            id: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            />
        </MemoryRouter>
    );
```